# Find greatest lower bound and least upper bound

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers and $≤$ be the partial order on $\mathbb{R}$.
Consider the subset
$$ A = \{ x ∈ \mathbb{R}: 1<x<2 \} $$
Find the greatest lower bound and least upper bound of $A$.

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

$$ A = \{ x ∈ \mathbb{R}: 1<x<2 \} $$
**Claim:** The least upper bound (l.u.b) of $A$ is $2$, and the greatest lower bound (g.l.b) of $A$ is $1$.

**Outline of proof:**
To show that $2$ is the l.u.b, show that it is an upper bound for $A$, and that if $u\in\mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $u\geq 2$.

Similarly to show that $1$ is the g.l.b, show that it is a lower bound for $A$, and that if $l \in\mathbb{R}$ is a lower bound for $A$ then $l\leq 1$.

The above outline really just *follows from the definitions*, and I hope you can fill in the details.

Comment: But in the relation, it says 1< x < 2 instead of 1≤ x ≤ 2 , so can 1 and 2 be included. This was what I got confused with..

Comment: Yes, the g.l.b and l.u.b of a set *may not necessarily* lie within the set!

Comment: Oh Okay, I didn't know that, Thanks :)